# Chrome adding tags (#shadow-root (open))

Tags: php, html

I have a div with some simple text inside, but whenever i apply the class "sidebar-ad" or "sidebar-advertisement", i get the following output:

[image]

I have searched my directory for "sidebar-ad" with Windows Grep, and I am not using this selector in my css, or in any js.
Currently i'm just using a different selector ("sidebar-ads"), but what exactly is happening here? I tested using this same class on another project which is on another server and i had the same thing happen.
What is this [hidden] tag that's being added? http://prntscr.com/cy5861

Sorry for the stupid question, but this is baffling me.

Thanks.

**Edit, i tested with Edge and this isn't happening there. What is Chrome doing?**

**Edit, it's also happening with "sidebar-ads", so i'm now using "ad" lol**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Adblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) extension modifying the HTML so your ads doesn't display.

If you disable it on this page, you will not see this css class anymore.

Comment: We commented at the same time! Thank you.